# Exporting Runnable Jar Not Working with ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, jar, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am having a issues with running a runnable jar file which has a image icon in it.

Code runs on eclipse nicely and displays the icon in a `JFrame`. The way I add it is by adding it to a `JLabel` and then adding that `JLabel` to the `JFrame`. I export the project into a runnable Jar file and when I double click the jar. It doesn't run.

I tested out just adding a normal `JLabel` onto the `JFrame` without the icon code and it works when I exported and ran it.

Whenever I add the following line to code, it messes the runnable Jar File.

```
JLabel s1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/Pattern1.png")));
```

I noticed it could be something wrong when it gets the resources. My Image Pattern1, is stored in a folder called Images and that folder is inside my project src folder. 
So I am sure it's in the runnable jar file when I export it.

Here my code

```
package main;


import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame {    

    public MyFrame() {
        JLabel s1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/Pattern1.png")));
        this.add(s1);

        //JLabel test = new JLabel("Test");
        //this.add(test);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is what my files in my project looks like.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Not sure it will make any difference, but have you tried `/Images/Pattern1.PNG`

Comment: Oh wow. It works with .PNG. That's really strange. Thanks mate.

Comment: Java can be a little "lazy" with files (especially on Windows), but embedded resources are named EXACTLY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especially on Windows, Java can be a lenient on the use of case within the file names.  When running in Eclipse, the `Pattern1.PNG` is probably been picked up off the file system directly.

Once embedded within the Jar however, the case matching becomes EXACT.  This is because the resource is simply added to a zip file and Java uses the Zip Entry information to find content.

Make sure you naming is EXACT to avoid issues.  Try `/Images/Pattern1.PNG` instead of `/Images/Pattern1.png`